# Pass variable to bash command with Python

Tags: python, bash, variables, cygwin

I have the next code:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen("C:/cygwin64/bin/bash.exe", stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)

path = "C:/Users/Link/Desktop/folder/"

p.stdin.write(b"cd " + str.encode(path)))

p.stdin.close()
out = p.stdout.read()
print(out)
```

The `output` is `b''`

Is there any way to pass a variable to the bash command `p.stdin.write(b"cd " + path)`

I ask because the way it is written above don't work. Output is null, just like Cygwin started and nothing else.

**EDIT**

As long as I see the question is not so clear, I'll add this scenario:

I am on Windows and I am using Python 3.6.
I have a bash cmd that requieres Cygwin to be executed. This cmd may have a variable in his string, which will change after every execution. Immagine a `for` loop which executes a command.

For example (an ImageMagick command):

```
convert image.jpg -resize 1024x768 output_file.jpg
```

How can I execute this cmd from Python with `output_file.jpg` as variable ?

Comment: Check `stderr`. It may be trying to tell you what's wrong.

Comment: There is nothing wrong. The code execute with exit 0. But it's like the variable isn't seen by the command.

Comment: What output are you expecting? `cd` does not print anything to stdout.

Comment: I expect that `p.stdin.write` to execute full command `cd C:/Users/Link/Desktop/folder/"`. Actually it does nothing, like it don't read the cmd.

Comment: @Link What makes you think it doesn't execute the command? Executing the command `cd C:/Users/Link/Desktop/folder/` successfully will not print anything, nor will it have any side effects outside the bash process it runs in (i.e. it will not change the directory of the python process).

Comment: Which Python are you using ? Windows or Cygwin one ?

Comment: @matzeri Python 3.6 with Cygwin on Windows 10

Comment: @GordonDavisson because printing `out` show only `b' '` and not the full path of the folder I changed with `cd`

Comment: I edited the question. Hope is clearer.

Comment: @Link As glenn jackman said, `cd` doesn't print the path of the directory it changes to, so that doesn't indicate anything. If you want to see that it changed directory, you need to make it print something that'll tell you whether it worked or not. Try `p.stdin.write(b"cd " + str.encode(path) + "; echo \"Now in: $PWD\"; ls")` and it should print the new directory and its contents.

Answer (score 0):

Bash doesn't run in *interactive mode* by default unless it detects that standard input and output are connected to a terminal. You `PIPE`d these in, therefore they're definitely not connected to a terminal.

Bash does not display any prompts in non-interactive mode, hence you see nothing. You can *force* it to be interactive with `-i` switch.

However, even then, it is not going to write to `stdout` but `stderr`; you can try piping stderr to stdout

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
p = Popen(["C:/cygwin64/bin/bash.exe", "-i"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
```

and you will capture the prompts and such.

Or use your original approach with a command that does produce output - here `pwd` that prints the current working directory:

```
p.stdin.write(b"cd " + path.encode() + b"\n")
p.stdin.write(b"pwd")
```

---

It is tricky to talk to an interactive process like this though - read too little => deadlock. Write too much => deadlock. This is why `Popen` has the `.communicate` method for providing all of input at once and getting the `stdout` and `stderr` afterwards.

Comment: Also of note, the shell uses stderr to echo your command back to you.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems you are using the Cygwin python, than you should use proper 
Posix paths and not Windows-like ones

Instead of

```
p = Popen("C:/cygwin64/bin/bash.exe", stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
```

use

```
p = Popen("/bin/bash.exe", stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
```

Comment: Yes, ok. But the problem remains. I updated the question to be more clearer.